# Solving a system of univariate polynomials

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations

How would one go about solving a system of homogeneous univariate polynomials. For instance,

$$a_1x^4+ ax^3 + bx^2 + cx = 0 $$
$$d_1x^4 +dx^3 + ex^2 + fx= 0 $$
$$g_1x^4 +gx^3+hx^2 + ix = 0$$
$$l_1x^4 + lx^3+ mx^2+ nx =0. $$
 I am interested in non-trivial solutions over $\mathbb{C}.$

Comment: there is no solution for such a system

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I've edited the question.

Comment: Nitpick: Those polynomials are not homogeneous. Homogeneous means that all the terms have the same degree. Tha's a pretty boring bunch of polynomials (for the purposes of finding zeros), if you only have a single variable, but anyway.

Comment: @KonKan Siding with user26857 here. If there were several variables, then you might have a case. An algorithm for solving the system would then involve Gröbner bases and/or other material from polynomial rings. But, even then, I would rule that the systems of polynomial equations one might encounter in a typical multivariable calculus problem (Lagrange multipliers, critical points etc) are absolutely not abstract algebra. Do read the tag wikis. They are there to guide the newcomers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x=0$ is an obvious solution. To look for others, divide the equations by $x$  then eliminate $x^2$ between the first two:

$$0=d(ax^2+bx+c)-a(dx^2+ex+f)=(bd-ae)x+(cd-af)$$

- If $bd-ae \ne 0$ then the above implies $x=\frac{af-cd}{bd-ae}$. Substitute this solution back into the $3$ original equations. If it satisfies them, then that's the unique non-$0$ solution. Otherwise there are no non-$0$ solutions.
- If $bd-ae = 0$ then if $cd-af \ne 0$ there are no no non-$0$ solutions. Otherwise if $cd-af=0$ the first two equations are identical but for a multiplicative factor. Drop one of them, then repeat the steps above for the remaining two equations.

Comment: Could you tell me if this is can generalised to the polynomials of the  4th degree, if I were to add another equation? I've edited the question.

Comment: Consider it a linear system in $t=x^4,u=x^3,v=x^2,w=x$. Then if the determinant of the coefficients $a_1, a,\cdots,d_1,d,\cdots,\cdots$ is non-0 then the system will only have the trivial solution $x=0$. Otherwise, divide by $x$ and eliminate $x^3,x^2$ between $3$ equations to obtain a linear equation in $x$. Solve it and verify that it satisfies the other equations.

Answer (score 3):

A general method for finding the solutions of a system of simultaneous polynomial equations
$$
f_1(x)=0, \ \ f_2(x)=0, \ \ ... \ \ f_n(x)=0
$$
is finding the $\gcd\big(f_1, f_2, ..., f_n\big)=g(x)$, of these polynomials.

Recall at this point that the ring $\mathbb{C}[x]$, i.e. the ring of polynomials with complex coefficients, is a PID (a principal ideal domain). This means that any of its ideals is a principal ideal, i.e. an ideal generated by a single element. In particular, regarding the ideal of $\mathbb{C}[x]$ generated by the polynomials $f_1, f_2, ..., f_n$, it can be shown that it is generated by their greatest common divisor: 
$$
<f_1, f_2, ..., f_n>=<\gcd\big(f_1, f_2, ..., f_n\big)>=<g>
$$ 
Thus, the solution of the initial system, is equivalent to the solution of the single equation
$$
g(x)=0
$$
**P.S.:** The $\gcd\big(f_1, f_2, ..., f_n\big)$, can be found either by straightforward factorization of the polynomials $f_1, f_2, ..., f_n$, or more generally using the Euclidean division algorithm for finding the $\gcd$ of two  univariate polynomials in $\mathbb{C}[x]$ together with the fact that for $n\geq 3$ 
$$
\gcd(f_1, f_2, ..., f_n)=\gcd\big(f_1,\gcd(f_2, ..., f_n)\big)
$$